# Doit-on dire "une occasion qui m'a permis d'avancer" ou "Une occasion qui m'a permisE d'avancer" ?

Tags: orthographe, accord, participe-passé

L'accord en genre de certains verbes au passé composé est mon plus grand défaut en orthographe.

Doit-on dire "une occasion qui m'a permis d'avancer" ou "Une occasion qui m'a permis**e** d'avancer" ?

Answer (score 4):

[...] qui m'a **permis** d'avancer.

On ne fait pas d'accord avec le sujet (occasion) avec l'auxiliaire avoir.

On ne fait pas d'accord avec *me* même s'il représente une personne de sexe féminin car c'est un complément d'objet indirect (à permis **à** qui ? à moi)

Le complément d'objet direct est *d'avancer* (à permis **quoi** ? d'avancer)

Pour qu'il y ait accord, il faudrait que le complément d'objet direct soit placé avant l'auxiliaire *avoir*, par exemple :

> *Je l'ai remercié pour la visite qu'il m'a **permise**.*

mais attention, pas d'accord dans :

> *Je l'ai remercié pour la visite qu'il m'a **permis** de faire.*

Dans ce dernier cas, on est en présence d'un complément d'objet indirect (pour la visite qu'il m'a permis **de** quoi ? de faire).

***De*** est une préposition dans ce dernier cas alors que c'est une particule de l'infinitif dans la phrase de la question.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Est-ce qu'on peut résumer la règle comme suit ?
Si le verbe est suivi de "de" = ne rien ajouter
Sinon, accorder en genre et en nombre

Edit : je viens de me rendre compte que cette règle ne fonctionne pas, car on peut ajouter un "de" à votre phrase en conservant l'accord :
> "Je l'ai remercié pour la visite qu'il m'a permise de faire"

Comment: Non, c'est un cas différent qui n'entraîne pas d'accord.